# how does numpy.linalg.norm ord=2 work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Numpy. I couldn't understand the use of ord=2 in numpy.linalg.norm. For example, what is the difference between:

```
np.linalg.norm(np.array([[-4, -3, -2],
                         [-1,  0,  1],
                         [ 2,  3,  4]]))
```

and

```
np.linalg.norm(np.array([[-4, -3, -2],
                         [-1,  0,  1],
                         [ 2,  3,  4]]),2)
```

In Numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), it is given that ord =2 means 2-norm (largest sing. value). I couldn't understand what is meant by largest singular value. Could you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are referring to the so called [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). Your operand is 2D and interpreted as the matrix representation of a linear operator. The operator norm tells you how much longer a vector can become when the operator is applied. The 2 refers to the underlying vector norm. The singular value definition happens to be equivalent.

As for the difference, the default is not the operator norm but the Frobenius norm which is the Euclidean norm if you interpret the matrix as a vector in `nxm` - space. Looking at examples (the easiest being the identity matrix) it is clear that the Frobenius and operator norms are different.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. The equivalent form for first piece of code is:


`import numpy as np
np.sum(np.abs(np.array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]]))**2)**(1./2)`

Could you tell me what is the equivalent formula when ord=2 is specified?

Comment: I can't give you a closed form solution. You have to find the largest solution `lam` of `A^T A x = lam x` where `A` is your matrix, `x` is a nonznero vector and `lam` is a scalar.

Comment: `np.linalg.norm(np.array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]]),2)`

yields 7.3484692283495345.

As per your comment, I tried this:
`A = np.array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
v = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
B = np.dot(A.T,A)
7.3484692283495345 * np.dot(B,v)`

This yields 
array([[749.54386129],
       [793.63467666],
       [837.72549203]])

whereas `7.3484692283495345 * v` yields
array([[ 7.34846923],
       [14.69693846],
       [22.04540769]])

What went wrong in the above code?

Comment: @MuthurajaPalaniappan (1) You must use the **square** of `7.34...` (2) You can't just take any vector `v` you must find the right one. You can indirectly check whether such a vector exists by computing `np.linalg.det(A.T @ A - np.linalg.norm(A,2)**2 * np.identity(3))` which is zero in that case.